# How can I add Attributes with the keycloak mappers and be able to see these Attributes in keycloak token?

Tags: attributes, keycloak, mapper

I am trying to define mappers to add additional information in the keycloak token from an external Identity Provider.
When I define these mappers I do not see any changes in the JWT token from keycloak.

I defined the mappers and I was expecting to see additional information in the jwt token from keycloak

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add a user attribute into JWT.

#### Overview

[image]

#### Step 1

Adding custom user attributes

[image]

#### Step 2

Adding the attribute into `profile` client scopes by configuration `Add mapper`

When you get the JWT token using OAuth flow, you got the “profile” scope.

[image]

#### Step 3

Get Access token using `axios` and `jwt-decode` library on `node.js`
You can be using `curl` or `Postman` too.

Save as `get-token.js` file name.

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const decode = require('jwt-decode')

const getUserToken = async (user_name, password) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            url = 'http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token',
            data = new URLSearchParams({
                'client_id': 'admin-cli',
                'username': user_name,
                'password': password,
                'grant_type': 'password'
            })
        )
        return resp.data.access_token
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
}

(async () => {
    const user_token = await getUserToken('user1', '1234')
    console.log('user_token JWT: ' + JSON.stringify(decode(user_token), null, 4))
})()
```

Install dependencies

```
npm install axios jwt-decode
```

Run it

```
node get-token.js
```

[image]